# How to intercept http POST data from web form

Tags: android, http, browser, intercept

I've a web page (being displayed in a browser, **NOT a WebView**), and I'd like to pass some data (using http POST for instance) to a regular android app.

I only need the app to be launched and fed with data. I know the app can be launched by registering an intent filter, but I'm lost on the data passing part.

There's no need for the URL to be real, a fake URL is fine.

This can be done in BlackBerry using HTTP filters. Is there a way to do the same thing in Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some SO Questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038958/launch-app-with-url

Comment: @user370305 Thanks, I've read them all. But, as I tried to explain in my question, I already know how to launch the app but not how to pass data.

Comment: check my blogspot `html and activity links` It contains info about passing data (using GET): http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/09/html-and-activity-links-in-textview.html

Comment: @Sherif +1 for showing how to use `getQueryParameter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your web page put links like:

```
<a href="my.special.scheme://xyz.com/data1/data2">
```

In your activity's `onCreate()` you can access the data through the intent object..

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "http"
String host = data.getHost(); // "xyz.com"
List<String> params = data.getPathSegments(); 
String first = params.get(0); // "data1"
String second = params.get(1); // "data2"
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would investigate into is to implement a very simple HTTP server service as part of your application. Coding a small web server for your exact purpose would be extremely simple: Listen on TCP port 80, accept incoming connection, then keep reading from socket until `\r\n\r\n` is seen to skip the header, and then read the POST data. Your web page would presumably access it via 'localhost'. Whether there are any major hurdles with this method I don't know, but on doing a quick search I've seen there are already small Android web servers available, so technically it seems possible.

Comment: Humm, but the service is a good candidate to be stopped by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents:

Although not actually intercepting, but this approach does the job using the conventional Intent Filter mechanism.

Example:

1. Browser opens a link to myownscheme://myfakeurl.fake/http%3A%2F%2Factualurl.com
2. Android app matches the intent filter and is launched. It parses the parameter in the URL and decodes it obtaining "http://actualurl.com"
3. The android app makes a connection to the passed url and fetches the data.

   ```
       String encodedURL = getIntent().getData().getPathSegments().get(0); //Returns http%3A%2F%2Factualurl.com
       String targetURL = Html.fromHtml(encodedURL); //Returns http://actualurl.com
       //Now do the GET and fetch the data.
   ```